# Is the word "conjure" used as dialect?

Tags: dialect

Malcolm's team trying to keep Alliance from River:

> Simon: Did he say anything about a Miranda?
>
> Inara: What is that?
>
> Zoe: Don't know who or what, but it's on River's mind.
>
> Malcolm: **Conjure it** might be the reason they're after her.

Is the word "conjure" used as dialect?

Comment: I think there are mistakes in your transcriptions or the script you are looking at. Why? Because all sorts of things at the beginning might be feasible: "[mystery word] might be the reason they're after her". But not: conjure it.  This might apply to your other questions as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, yes. It is an abbreviation of the colloquialism "*I* conjure it might be..." which means "I think it might be." Compare "I reckon it might be..." which is also colloquial.

But in other contexts "conjure" can be used as an example of good standard English, like the phrase "to conjure up [something]."

Comment: Do you know for a fact that is a colloquialism? Even if it were, the truncated form makes no sense here. I've never heard it.

Comment: "Reckon it might be" makes no grammatical sense either, that's part of what makes it a colloquialism, but it's definitely something I could imagine hearing in an old Western. The idea that "conjure" (likely as a mishearing of "[conjecture](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conjecture)") could be misused to mean "reckon" or "guess" makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: If Miranda is a thing, and I conjure it means I reckon, it does mean something. All these questions have issues, and it may not even be they are what was actually said in the video or movie.

Answer (score 1):

"Conjure" has a sense of "imagine or form a picture in the mind".

It is rare and non-standard to use it in the context you have given, but it would mean:

> I imagine it might be the reason they are after her.

As with most of the other pieces of dialogue you have asked about.  This is not regular English, nor is it a slang.  It is a use that has been made up by the scriptwriters to evoke the space-cowboy feel of the show. (Another aspect of this invented slang is dropping the subject of sentences. In my rephrasing I've put back the implied "I".)